# Update cordova to version 3.5.0

Tags: ubuntu, cordova, npm, cordova-3

I have Cordova installed in my project (version 3.4.0-0.1.3) and I am trying to update it to version 3.5.0-0.2.7
I am running the command

```
sudo npm update -g cordova@3.5.0-0.2.7
```

and  it works fine.
When I run

```
npm ls -g | grep cordova
```

I get:

```
├─┬ cordova@3.5.0-0.2.7
│ ├─┬ cordova-lib@0.21.7 
│ │ ├─┬ cordova-js@3.6.2 
│ │ ├─┬ cordova@3.1.0-0.1.0 
│ ├─┬ cordova@3.4.0-0.1.2
```

But when I run

```
cordova -v
```

I still get the same version I had before 3.4.0-0.1.3

Why can't I update my project?
There must be something I'm missing...

I need to update cordova to build my project, please help!

Thanks

Comment: have you tried `install` instead of `update`?

Comment: Was cordova installed as root to begin with, i.e with sudo? Also, what is the output of `npm ls -g`? `sudo npm ls -g`?

Comment: Yes, I tried install too.

Comment: Anyone knows what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue on Ubuntu 14.04. when trying to upgrade to Cordova 3.6.3. It seems that npm -g installs modules to

```
/usr/bin/cordova -> /usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova
```

But the output of

```
which cordova
```

showed this:

```
/usr/local/bin/cordova
```

And that symlink was pointing to another nnode_modules installation:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova
```

I'm no Node/npm specialist...so I'm not sure what the correct path is and where the installations in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` come from. But since nmp -g installed into `/usr/lib/node_modules`...I've deleted the `/usr/local/bin/cordova` symlink and afterwards everything worked fine.

Edited:
When I delete `/usr/local/bin/cordova` I get bash error `/usr/local/bin/cordova not exists`. To solve it create correct symlink with

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/cordova /usr/local/bin/cordova
```